# How to get the total number of fishes on a video

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray, motion-detection

I've been given a video consisting of frames like this:

[image: frame]

and I am supposed to count how many of fishes went in front of the screen during the video using **Python**. I am **not allowed to use OpenCV** or similar library. The only library I am allowed to use is **PIL** and **Numpy**, therefore I am forced to use numpy matrices as the image representation.

So far I am able to generate this one channel image mask:

[image: grey frame]

which I believe should be enough to detect fishes on one frame. However now I need to somehow track those fishes throughout the remaining frames to distinguish those fishes who were already on the screen and those who moved in.

What would be the procedure to do that? I'm imagining somehow marking those areas and then predicting the movement of those fishes or something.

Comment: You can use Mask R-CNN it will give you the number of fishes and his mask.

Comment: how t-did you got th second image ??? ist it faster than openV findcounturs ??

Comment: The median over all frames should give you a good background, which you can compare each frame against to find the fish. Then you probably want to find corresponding fish from frame to frame, by matching shapes in one frame to the next. Depending on the speed of the fish, you might get away with just assigning the nearest detections.